# Saving user data google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create my first Google Chrome extension. The following explains what I want with the extension and then what my question is.

I want to create an extension that runs with Linkedin. Users can input parameters in the extension (with an html ) and this input and all the past inputs of the user is then saved into a list. Then this would potentially be compared with linkedin connections (if they have the extension) and connections with the same inputs will show up in the extension.

What I am trying to do now would be to have the user's list show up in the extension. I've looked into storage, mainly "chrome.storage.sync.set" but I am not sure it works in my case (as I am just starting out, I understand very little). I guess that potentially he would have to sign in, so that to each user is associated a list.

my popup.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      button {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        outline: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    Job: <input type="text" name="Job" value="FB"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

my background.js like this:

```
// Copyright 2018 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

'use strict';


chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({color: '#3aa757'}, function() {
    console.log('The color is green.');
  });
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ "yourBody": "myBody" }, function() {
    console.log('Body has been saved');
  });
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
      conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
        pageUrl: { urlContains: 'linkedin' },
      })
      ],
          actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
    }]);
  });
});
```

Maybe what I am trying to do is just not possible (userMe can compare data entered in extension with any user that is in his/her connections), and in that case I'd be happy if someone could tell me if it is not.

Cheeers

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve and what's preventing you from doing that. What is "connections with the same inputs"? There seems to be a lot of unnecessary info in the question e.g. the posted code is fine but it doesn't do anything useful or relevant. In case you needed an example, here's some: [chrome.storage for Chrome extension](//stackoverflow.com/a/47401395)

Comment: I agree, it's hard to understand other than you want an extension to compare 'data entered in extension with any user that is in his/her connections'.    You need a chrome.storage.sync.get at the top of your page.  Unless you put it in another file and load it from the HTML....